# Version mismatch between tsc compiler and VS Code's language service

Tags: visual-studio-code

I just started playing with Visual Studio Code and when I created a new file called index.html, I am shown this warning message

***A version mismatch between the globally installed tsc compiler (1.0.3.0) and VS Code's language service (1.8.10) has***

Can someone please guide me what i have to do to fix this.

Is this serious or I can ignore. I googled but could not get much info

Thanks

[image]

Comment: See also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-the-workspace-version-of-typescript

Answer (score 28):

I added this to my `settings.json` file, accessed through `preferences > Workspace Settings` :

`"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"`

now I no longer receive this error and in the bottom right corner of my screen it shows the current version of Typescript that I have installed.

Comment: This is the correct answer on Windows (no need for the long explicit path)

Comment: File > Preferences > Workspace Settings (Thanks to https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/userandworkspace)

Comment: On Windows, when I used `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"`, I get a warning `The path c:\temp\typescript\code\node_modules\typescript\lib doesn't point to a valid tsserver install. Falling back to bundled TypeScript version.` I had to use the full path. `"typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\wekel\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"` I am using VS Code 1.9.1.

Answer (score 21):

[UPDATE] `VS Code 1.6 now ships with TypeScript 2.0.3`.

I just installed the latest Typescript, currently `v.2.0.3`, and installed VS Code `v.1.5.3` on macOS Sierra. For some reason, exactly following the official doc didn't work for me.

Here's how I made it work:

After having installed the latest version globally:
`npm i -g typescript`, I added the following line to my `settings.json` file (opened by `cmd + ,`):

`"typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib",`

Hope this helps someone else.

**[update]** as @ptpaterson mentioned on the comment below, on Windows the path is: `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/{user_name}/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/"`

Comment: `"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/{user_name}/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/" ` for me on windows.  But this is what I needed.

Comment: Thank you for that @ptpaterson. I added this info to the answer.

Comment: @rafaelbiten There's two hidden characters in your windows path. `/types^^cript/lib` . Please remove them

Comment: @AbuAbdullah Just removed the hidden spaces. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You have to change the version of TypeScript that Visual Code is using to match the version you have installed:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

The above is taken from the link:

> If you want to use a newer version of TypeScript, you can define the typescript.tsdk setting (File > Preferences > User/Workspace Settings) pointing to a directory containing the TypeScript tsserver.js file.
>
> You can find the installation location using npm list typescript, tsserver.js is usually under the lib folder.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> {
>     "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"
> }
> ```

Answer (score 9):

This error was being generated because I had a reference to an older installation of TypeScript in my System Path variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\
```

The Visual Studio Code error was resolved when I removed this entry.

However, my TypeScript files then failed to transpile as the build action couldn't find the `tsc.exe` file.

When the SDK is installed (through Visual Studio or via a manual `*.visx` install), a `tsc.exe` file is installed and the PATH environment variable is updated to reference the folder that this file resides in (see above).

There is another way to transpile your files on a Windows environment by using node.js:

- Install node.js.  Installation packages can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).
- Use npm to install TypeScript:

  `npm install -g typescript`

  This will add the TypeScript files to your profile `AppData` folder:

  `C:\Users\{your_user_name}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\typescript\lib`
- Configure your Visual Studio Code **user** `settings.json` file to reference this folder:

  ```
  {
  "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\{your_user_name}\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib"
  }
  ```
- Add / update the **user** PATH environment variable to reference the folder that contains the `tsc.cmd` file:

  `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm`

Answer (score 8):

You have to update your Typescript installation and restart Code afterwards:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

or

```
npm install -g typescript@1.8.10
```

The message should not longer appear, if it worked.

Comment: I did not work. I had to suppress the message by clicking dont check again.

Answer (score 5):

None of the solutions above worked for me - first of all this is the global tsc I want to have updated to the latest version.

After I did some investigation it turned out that the problem lies in system's PATH variables; **tsc.cmd** (along with **tscserver.cmd**) exists in these locations:

- **c:\Program Files\nodejs** - where the npm.exe and node.exe are
- **%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm** - where global packages are

What you can do is to juggle environment\user variables so the **tsc** command would be resolved from **%USERPROFILE%** first instead of **Program Files**.

The quick & dirty way would be just deleting **tsc.cmd** and **tscserver.cmd** from the **Program Files** path.

Answer (score 4):

Installing v2.0.3 of typescript was not sufficient... but but then updating the version dependency on package.json worked for me.

Npm command:

```
npm install -g typescript@2.0.3
```

Updated line on package.json:

```
"typescript": "^2.0.3"
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause of my experience with this issue (in VSCode 1.8 on Mac OS X 10.12.2) was that I have been using NVM and while my code was running on the NVM version, VSCode was looking at a system installation of node.

Double check which installation of npm you are using to install typescript globally. If in doubt (on linux/mac) use `which tsc` from the command-line to verify the location being used by VSCode.

For example, if I simply call `npm i -g typescript`, `npm` resolves to `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.9.1/bin/npm`. I had to solve the problem by calling `/usr/local/bin/npm i -g typescript` explicitly because VSCode looks for node in `/usr/local/bin/node` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Install TypeScript globally to share the installation across workspaces. In this case, you install it using `npm install -g typescript@next`.

You then have to tell VS Code on `setting.json` file (`File -> Preferences -> Workspace Settings`) the install location using the typescript.tsdk setting. Set typescript.tsdk to the path of the lib folder containing the `tsserver.js` file of the installed TypeScript module.

On windows: 
`"typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/<MyUser>/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib"`

On Mac: 
`"typescript.tsdk": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib"`

Answer (score 1):

Installing VSCode 1.6.0 fixed the TypeScript version mismatch warning message for me.

Answer (score 0):

You'd think that this being a Microsoft product they'd give the Windows paths on their website

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

but they don't. They only give the Unix path types.
Use:-
On windows: "typescript.tsdk": "C:/Users/YourNameHere/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib/"

Note that forward strokes must be used even though Windows uses backstrokes for the paths!

Some other answers miss off the last forward stroke which is necessary.

Comment: On windows, use escaped backslashes for paths: `"C:\\Users\\YourNameHere\\AppData\\...`

Comment: Sorry mate, but voted this down because this does not seem an answer but it is rather a comment. If you meant it to be an answer, then it seems irrelevant to the problem. Perhaps you could edit it to be more clear about how does the path and the path format solve this issue or remove it and place this as a comment where it belongs. I'll vote it up then. :)

Comment: @AlexRebula I'm not allowed to make any comments on other user's answers and the more I get voted down the further that possibility is.

Comment: Hey Quentin. You have a point there if that is so. :) I tried voting it back up, but it said that since I already voted it, your answer must be edited first. See http://prntscr.com/g16eai

Comment: Perhaps edit it a little and I'll cast back my vote for you. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe just editing by explaining why are you describing the path and its format. Otherwise the feedback you wrote is useful. It just looked out of context as an answer alone. Sorry for any inconvenience. Did not want to discourage you. As said, good feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remove 'typescript.tsdk' and use the one embedded in Code if you don't really care about which tsdk version you use.