# How do I upgrade typescript in Visual Studio Code version 1.9.1

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I received a message

> Version mismatch! global tsc (2.0.2) != VS Code's language service (2.1.6). Inconsist

I Googled it and tried what was suggested but the problem remains. Please help

[Version mismatch between tsc compiler and VS Code's language service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505048/version-mismatch-between-tsc-compiler-and-vs-codes-language-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global installed version of type script is not the one that came with Visual Studio Code. This impacts the debugger , editor etc, not the actual running of the code.

In Visual Studio Code you can update the user settings to override the installed settings of Visual Studio Code.

So assuming you used Npm to install type script and that version is newer or different, you can use the same version inside Visual Studio Code.
There are project based or system based ways to do this. I found the easiest is to add this to the user specific settings.

This is done easily inside Visual Studio Code.

Open Visual Studio Code GUI, open the Files Menu then  Preferences Menu and  User Settings.

Add this setting to the user settings:

```
{ "typescript.tsdk": "C:\\Users\\userName\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\typescript\\lib" }
```

This is for windows.

More complete instructions here for other operating systems:
[Use Specific Version of TypeScript with VS Code](https://gist.github.com/tonysneed/bb6d442103a057578a9498f106e45ac5)

Answer (score 3):

This error just means that the version of the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) you have installed for command line compiling does not match the version of TypeScript that VSCode uses for Intellisense. This may result in VSCode showing or not show showing errors in the editor compared to what `tsc` would show when it is used to compile the same code.

If you are only working in JS, don't worry about this error. I've disabled it for JS projects in VSCode 1.10

Two possible fixes for TypeScript projects:

**Update your global tsc install**

```
npm install -g typescript@2.2.1
```

Also make sure `tsc` on the command line points to the path of the newly installed version of TypeScript.

**Use a local Version of TypeScript for VSCode Language Features**

Install TypeScript locally:

```
npm install --save-dev typescript@2.2.1
```

and update your workspace settings to use this version of typescript in VSCode:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "./node_modules/typescript/lib"
}
```

Here are the complete instructions for configuring a local version of TypeScript:
https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions

---

**Update March 6, 2017**

Use TS 2.2.1 instead of 2.1.6 in example

Answer (score 0):

the source of this problem and another approach in my answer in another thread:

[Version mismatch between tsc compiler and VS Code's language service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39505048/version-mismatch-between-tsc-compiler-and-vs-codes-language-service/42735784?sfb=2#42735784)