# How to upgrade VS Code's own internal typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I see it has its own ts version like so:

How can I update this? Currently the latest version is 4.9.3.

[image]

Comment: I thought that this is bound to vscode's typescript version in `package.json` but with `1.73.1` installed I still see `4.8.4` but on github it's [`^4.9.0-dev.20221024`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/1.73.1/package.json#L210)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I upgrade typescript in Visual Studio Code version 1.9.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407569/how-do-i-upgrade-typescript-in-visual-studio-code-version-1-9-1)

Answer (score -1):

This might be silly, since my TS version is higher than yours:

I haven't done anything specific besides updating VS Code itself to the latest version (Mac):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have 1.73.1 (user setup) for windows

Comment: @omega this seems relative and useful for your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676463/14701509

it seems that there's no way to update VS Code TS automatically, but install it globally